# Python Pandas hierarchical (tuple) row indexing -- how to select all of an intermediate row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, hierarchical

Consider the following code:

```
row1 = [(2,2), (4,4)]
row2 = [(5,5)]
row3 = [10, 20, 30, 40]
row_tuple_list = []
for r1 in row1:
    for r2 in row2:
        for r3 in row3:
            row_tuple_list.append((r1, r2, r3))

row_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(row_tuple_list, names=['row1', 'row2', 'row3'])

col1 = ['f', 'i']
col2 = ['g', 'h']
col_tuple_list = []
for c1 in col1:
    for c2 in col2:
        col_tuple_list.append((c1, c2))

col_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(col_tuple_list, names=['col1', 'col2'])

df = pd.DataFrame(index=row_index, columns=col_index)
```

which generates a dataframe:

```
col1                  f         i     
col2                  g    h    g    h
row1   row2   row3                    
(2, 2) (5, 5) 10    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
              20    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
              30    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
              40    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
(4, 4) (5, 5) 10    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
              20    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
              30    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
              40    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Now, I'd like to set individual elements of this dataframe.  For example,

```
w=(2,2)
x=(5,5)
y=10

df.loc[(w,x,y),('f','g')] = 200 

print(df)
```

which gives:

```
col1                  f         i     
col2                  g    h    g    h
row1   row2   row3                    
(2, 2) (5, 5) 10    200  NaN  NaN  NaN
              20    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
              30    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
              40    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
(4, 4) (5, 5) 10    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
              20    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
              30    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
              40    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Is there a way to do this without explicitly setting the second row value (since I known that row1 and row2 occur with the same frequency)?

I tried:

```
df.loc[(w,slice(None),y),('f','g')] =100
```

which fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# you need to use slice for w as well. This should work.
df.loc[(slice(w),slice(None),y),('f','g')]

df
Out[208]: 
col1                  f         i     
col2                  g    h    g    h
row1   row2   row3                    
(2, 2) (5, 5) 10    100  NaN  NaN  NaN
              20    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
              30    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
              40    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
(4, 4) (5, 5) 10    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
              20    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
              30    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: That's great!  It seems I don't understand what slice is doing here.  Could you please explain why I need to use slice(w) as well?

Comment: Also, if you have any idea on this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43664161/pandas-dataframe-columns-with-different-data-rates-for-hierarchical-columns-a), it would be most appreciated!

Comment: df.loc[(w,slice(None),y),('f','g')] should work but it does't work for your Dataframe. I think it has something to do with the parenthesis around your index '(2,2)'. It may have somehow messed up with pandas indexing. This should also work without adding slice to w. df.loc[([w],slice(None),y),('f','g')]

Comment: quick follow up question:  Could you please tell me how to access this same quantity after having set its value?    df.loc[([w],slice(None),y),('f','g')]  gives me:     row1    row2    row3
(2, 2)  (5, 5)  10      100
Name: (f, g), dtype: object       rather than just 100.